# jQuery count number of divs with a particular class inside a div with a particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I count the number of div's with class `item` that are inside the div with class `outer-1`? The result here should be 7.

I tried this and several other failed variations of it.

```
alert( $(".outer-1").$(".item").length );
```

This gives me `12` which is all the divs on the page.
`alert( $(".item").length );`

How can i specify only the `outer-1` div?

**Divs**

```
<div class="outer-1">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">d</div>
    <div class="item">e</div>
    <div class="item">f</div>
    <div class="item">g</div>
</div>

<div class="outer-2">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">d</div>
    <div class="item">e</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `find()` selector:

```
$(".outer-1").find(".item").length ;
```

or

```
 $(".outer-1 .item").length
```

Comment: Or `$(".outer-1 .item").length` :)

Answer (score 0):

For your html, `$(".outer-1 .item").length` would be sufficient, but if `div.item`s are nested, like this

```
<div class="outer-1">
    <div class="item">a</div>
    <div class="item">b</div>
    <div class="item">c</div>
    <div class="item">d</div>
    <div class="outer-x">
      <div class="item">h</div>
      <div class="item">i</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">e</div>
    <div class="item">f</div>
    <div class="item">g</div>
</div>
```

You may want to use `$(".outer-1 > .item").length` (all `div.item` that are child of `div.outer-1`).

[**See jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/vooo38cx/)

Answer (score 0):

if you have a bunch of outers with the same name, you may need to loop:

```
$('.outer-1').each(function(){
   console.log( $('.item',this).length );
});
```