# How to count individual items in different containers with the same class?

Tags: jquery

Look for similar questions I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7404544/jquery-count-number-of-divs-with-a-certain-class) and this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711988/jquery-count-number-of-divs-with-a-particular-class-inside-a-div-with-a-particul)

But this does not work for me when I have the same container to which I want to count the articles that each container has, for example:

```
<div id="slider">
    <button class="btn"></button>
    <button class="btn"></button>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="slider">
    <button class="btn"></button>
    <button class="btn"></button>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I need is to be able to hide the buttons that have less than or equal to 4 articles (`<div class="item"></div>`), I have tried the following, but it hides all the buttons even those that have more than 5 articles (`<div class="item"></div>`).

```
$(".slider").each(function(){
    var numItems = $(this).find("div.item").length;
    if (numItems <= 4) {
        $('button.btn').css('display','none');
    }
});
```

What changes do I need to make to make it work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('button.btn').css('display','none');` will hide *all* buttons. To hide just the buttons inside the sliders with 4 or fewer articles, try:

`$(this).find('button.btn').css('display','none');`

Explanation: `$(this)` starts at the slider you're up to in the `.each()` loop. Then, `.find('button.btn')` finds just the buttons that are descendants of that particular slider.

Comment: I know why it does not work for me, what happens is that the buttons are in another container, I copied the wrong example of my question, can you help me please https://jsfiddle.net/e2yk8szx/

Comment: You have multiple instances of `<div id="slider">`. IDs must be unique, so you will need to change that first.

Comment: I have another similar question with reward, will it help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69052314/carousel-multiple-how-to-make-arrows-target-a-specific-set-of-slides